# How to include JS file in HTML, using NodeJS Express server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm creating a chat, using server `Express` of `NodeJS` and `AngularJS` for manager in client side

But when I try include `/js/code.js` in my `html`, it can not found, because is not routed by `Express`

```
<!-- my include in html -->
<script src="./js/code.js"></script> <!- this is not found in execution -->
```

Meu index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

How to can I fix this problem, without route all js file I will using in my project or routing all js file in path a lot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use app.use to specify your public files to your node app, like below

```
app.use(express.static(yourPublicPath));
```

EDIT:

You are getting "Express undefined" error because it is not defined. You can easily fix this by defining your app in 2 stages:-

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

On a side note, I would strongly recommend to go through Expressjs docs to learn more about Express.

Comment: This returning error "express is not defined", I need require any module?

Comment: I need define this static, before of my routes?

Comment: I would rather suggest you find this yourself. Play with it, try different options. That will help you understand how a node app works.

Comment: Okey, I will try this way! Thank you very much

Comment: This is working!! I read Express docs how to work this function, thank you very very much!!